# Не получается вызвать клик по элементу

Tags: javascript, jquery

На сайте [ссылка](https://pkk5.rosreestr.ru/#x=4069269.3700378463&y=7576732.37734637&z=8&text=56%2C021355%2036%2C593321&type=1&app=search&opened=1)

Когда кликнуть на карту в любое место появляется такое окошко:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я пытаюсь на Jquery сделать имитацию клика сюда:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот мой код:

```
var nextPage = $('.tundra #app-search-results #searchEngine-featureSetContainer #searchEngineFeatureSet_pagination ul.pagination li a').last();
nextPage.trigger('click');
```

Но сайт не реагирует на этот клик почему-то. Как будто не туда кликаю...

В чем может быть дело? Буду очень благодарен за помощь!

Comment: А как вы запускаете свой скрипт? Если просто открыть страницу, в консоли ввести ваш код, то всё работает. Может быть вы не дожидаетесь, когда на элемент навесится обработчик, и пытаетесь кликнуть слишком рано?

Comment: @ЕгорБанин через Tampermonkey

Comment: Так вы дожидаетесь? У вас это по кнопке запускается или автоматом? Просто если скрипты на странице ещё не отработали, то на кнопке не будет обработчика, событие для которого вы тригерите. Пробовали задержку устанавливать?

Comment: @ЕгорБанин а как установить задержку? я делал по setTimeout

Answer (score 0):

Надо просто подождать, когда элемент появится на экране. Можно написать функцию ожидания или просто подождать какое-то достаточное время.

Попробовал сделать через простой setTimeout:

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    window.setTimeout(function() {
        var navLinks = document.querySelectorAll('ul.pagination li a');
        var nextLink = navLinks.item(navLinks.length - 1);
        nextLink.click();
    }, 5000);
})();
```

работает.